# Refine the 'telecommuting' concept on careers site

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Lately I've been looking for a "pure" telecommute/work from home type job.

However, when I search for jobs lately using the checkbox for "Only show telecommuting jobs" I find that about half, sometimes more, of the positions listed are positions where they indicate that you can "telecommute partially" or offer telecommuting as a benefit to their employees.

I think it would be great to either refine the definition of a telecommuting to be more strict, or offer a "virtual office" type of option when searching for positions. I realize that the employers would need to refine how they post positions, but I think all would benefit.